# How does Stack Overflow not have "x questions with new activity" on the home page?

Tags: support, web-sockets

It is known that Stack Overflow (main site) does not have "x question(s) with new activity" banner due to the traffic being heavy. It is also known that such information is delivered via websocket + AJAX.

Since there isn't such thing on SO, there might be two reasons (implementations):

1. The `1-home-activity` action of SE's master WSS does not send any data.
2. SO's main page does not register such an action, but that action exists and behaves normally when a client registers it.

Which one is true? I need to know this because I'm developing something wacky based on that. If the answer is 1 then I need to find some workarounds.

Comment: The probable answer is a lot more duh than you hoped for.  All of the questions on the home page have new activity.  That's how they ended up on the home page.

Comment: @HansPassant I mean the *banner* which is available on all SE sites except SO main.

Comment: Couldn't this easily be found out by looking at the JavaScript code and doing some simple tests?

Comment: For performance reasons you can't subscribe to frames for that type.

Comment: @rene Is there any other way to do this? One possible approach is to subscribe to the realtime tab and ignoring all non-SO posts.

Comment: @iBug you could subscribe to all tags: `<siteid>-questions-newest-tag-<tagname>`.